# recursively replace echo value with previously echoed value in Unix

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I want to print a loop like below

```
a=0
while [ $a -lt 100 ]
do
   echo ${a}%
   a=`expr $a + 1`
   sleep 1
done
```

It throws output as follows

```
1%
2%
3%
4%
...
```

But I wanted to print like running value `1%` replaced by `2%`, etc. till `100%` in the same line.

Comment: ...not sure what you mean by ‘recursively’, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `printf` to print backspace character `\b` to remove the already printed characters as

```
printf "\b%.0s" {1..5}
```

- This will print `5` backspaces where by the cursor will be moved to the start of the line.

  In the next iteration the the echo will produce the new number

**Example**

```
while [ $a -lt 100 ]
do    
    echo -n ${a}%;    
    a=`expr $a + 1`

    #This will remove the already printed value from the screen
    printf "\b%.0s" {1..5}
    sleep 1
done
```

**OR**

You can `echo` a carriage return as

```
echo -e "\r"
```

like

```
while [ $a -lt 100 ]
do    
    echo -n ${a}%;    
    a=`expr $a + 1`

    #This will remove the already printed value from the screen
    echo -e "\r"
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: A carriage return `\r` seems more appropriate to me.

Comment: @RamboRamon Even that is fine. Which is a much more less confusing code than the `printf`. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function a(){
  if [[ $1 -le 100 ]]; then
    echo $1%
    b=`expr $1 + 1`
    sleep 1
    clear
    a $b
  fi
}
a 0
```

I think that this is you want... count 0 to 100 with recursivity in the same line